# Node package structuring

Tags: node.js, npm, structure

I have folder of util methods, 50+, and they are divided in two folders, db and utils.
The methods are all in different files within those two folder
How ever when I call the package

I want to do be able to simply do:

```
let { db, utils } = require ('utils')

db.insertRecord("Lucas")
utils.parseName("Lucas")
```

Instead of having to filter through each file

```
let { insertRecord } = require ('utils').db.recordsFile
let { parseName } = require ('utils').utils.parserFile


db.insertRecord("Lucas")
utils.parseName("Lucas")
```

So I created an index inside of utils and db to aggregate all the methods
but not sure where to go from here

Any help is appreciated

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say the folder structure of your `utils` package looks like this:

```
├── db
|  ├── getEmail.js
|  ├── getUser.js
|  └── index.js
├── index.js
└── utils
   ├── index.js
   ├── toArray.js
   └── toString.js
```

In `db` folder, create an `index.js` file:

```js
// db/index.js

module.exports = {
    getEmail: require('./getEmail'),
    getUser: require('./getUser')
}
```

In `utils` folder, create an `index.js`:

```js
// utils/index.js

module.exports = {
    toArray: require('./toArray'),
    toString: require('./toString')
}
```

At the root of your package, create an `index.js`:

```js
// index.js

module.exports = {
    db: require('./db'),
    utils: require('./utils'),
}
```

And we're done.

Answer (score 0):

Usually people will do the following:

utils/db.js

```js
exports.insertRecord = () => {
 .....
}
```

index.js

```
const { insertRecord } = require('utils/db');
```